# Why is reflect-metadata only working when using a decorator?

Tags: typescript, reflect-metadata

Without decorators the metadata is lost - but why?

```
const Baz = () : ClassDecorator => {
  return target => {}
}
class Bar {}
@Baz()
class Foo {
  constructor(bar: Bar) {}
}
console.log(Reflect.getMetadata('design:paramtypes', Foo));
```

This returns `[Function: Bar]`, which is fine. But without the `@Baz` decorator (which does literally nothing) it returns `undefined`. Why?

Comment: Then it doesn't literally do nothing ;-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/2589) that implements this feature states:

> emit design-time type metadata for **decorated** declarations in source.

So it explicitly was designed to emit metadata just if there is a decorator on a class.

I am unable to find the rationale behind this decision, but my guess it that it would be wasteful to emit this code for all classes (js is sensitive to size) and decorators and metadata are seen as related concepts.

Comment: Weird solution.

Comment: You sir are a life saver. Thank you.

Comment: Omg. Any idea why it must be decorated? It makes no sense for me.